# How to create object or array that will start from specific number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to create object or array that will start loop from #32. I have tried something like this:

```
var test = [{'recID':"32",'optionalCol':"first",'recID':"33",'optionalCol':"last",'recID':"34",'optionalCol':"age"}];
```

This did not work for me, I tried to do the loop like this:

```
for(var i=32; i < test.lenght; i++) {
    console.log(test[i].recID);
}
```

I'm wondering if this is possible and how my object/array has to be structured in order to be able to start my loop from 32? If anyone can help please let me know.

Comment: It should be `test.length` not `test.lenght`, not sure if that was just a typo.

Comment: is 32 a index? or is it related to the recID? like you need to start iterating where recID = 32?

Comment: Also, your test parameter is not array, it is an object. So you can't reach its elements by indexing (that's why test[32] doesn't work)

Comment: I should start my loop from 32 so my recID should be an index.

Comment: your properties get overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to use associative array like this:

```
var test = {
    32: "first",
    33: "last",
    34: "age"
}
```

You can iterate the object like this:

```
for (t in test) {
    console.log(test[t])
}
```

Or just access an item quickly like this:

```
console.log(test[33])
```

Check out the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xo0vuejt/

Comment: @MartinGotteweis How I can check the length of test variable? Usually I was doing this with test.length but I'm not sure that will work in this case.

Comment: `.length` is for arrays only. You can use `Object.keys(test).length`. The `Object.keys()` will take the object and return the array of the object's keys.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Object with the numbers as keys and with objects inside, which reflects the values in your given example.

```
var test = {
    32: {
        'recID': "32",
        'optionalCol': "first"
    },
    33: {
        'recID': "33",
        'optionalCol': "last"
    },
    34: {
        'recID': "34",
        'optionalCol': "age"
    }
};
```

This structure allows to access a property with

```
test[33].optionalCol
```

Iterate with

```
Object.keys(test).forEach(function (key, i, keys) {
    // test[k] ...
});
```

Count of properties of the object

```
Object.keys(test).length // 3
```